# ctrl+alt+l still logging out after disabling in Ubuntu Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

Some Ubuntu stock keyboard shortcuts are interfering with IntelliJ applications (PhpStorm in my case). I disabled the logout keymap by launching Settings > Keyboard > Shortcut, selecting the logout keymap and pressing "backspace". Still, when I press ctrl+alt+l the screen locks.

Is there a file where these keymaps are stored that I can examine?

Comment: try again and just press the - button. if doesnt work restart the computer.

Comment: I see the same with 16.04.  On my desktop which currently runs 17.10 I managed to disabled it - I guess around 17.04.